Determining the focal shift using ABCD or in other words ray transfer matrix
Determining the focal length after light passes through a lens is straightforward when the focus is in air, but how should we approach calculating the focal length when the light passes through a different medium, such as inside a water-filled aquarium but the lens is outside the aquarium, how can we find the focal point or focal shift? using the ABCD matrix....
